# Uso Godot y me tira error mí script por qué?

Tags: godot-engine, gdscript

Uso Godot y me tira error mí script por qué?

```
extends KinematicBody2D

const GRAVITY = 800
var velocity = Vector2()

func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.y += GRAVITY * delta
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)
    
    if is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = 0
```

Comment: Pero cuéntanos: ¿Que error te tira? y ¿que versión de godot usas?

Comment: Nota, cambia tu etiqueta de javascript a GDScript. Este es el script usado por godot. ¿Porque hacerlo?; Asi tienes mas confianza que los que saben de godot vengan. Pero con JavaScript...